# Deleting Outlook Category via Microsoft Graph API does not remove it from mails

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, categories, microsoft-graph-mail

I have an outlook category and some mails with that category, I use the Microsoft Graph API to delete the category.

The category gets removed from the list of categories and I can also not retrieve it from the API with a get request after deletion. However I can still see it attached to my mails in a grayed out tag.
[Here you can see one tag is shown grayed out, that's the deleted category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzjsz.png). How do I delete a category and remove it from my mails as well?

Can this be done without multiple queries where I fetch all mails with the category and then update all of them by removing the category?

Answer (score 1):

Category is just another property on a message, it can be set to any value. Category list is only for the user convenience so they can select from a list of values.

Modifying a category will do absolutely nothing to any messages where that category is used. That needs to be done separately one message at a time.